# CSS box shadow conflicting with pseudo-element

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-filters

Is there a way to disable the box shadow for the part where the pseudo-element arrow resides?

Current:

[image]

or without the negative `z-index` on the pseudo-element:

[image]

**Desired result**:

[image]

```css
#element { 
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #222;
}

#element::after {
    content: "";
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: blue;
    top: 40px;
    left: 88px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222); 
}
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't control which parts of a box shadow or a drop shadow filter are rendered, at least not directly.

Depending on your layout, you could cheat by patching another pseudo-element over the one that you have. I swap the `::after` with a `::before` to obviate the need for `z-index` because boxes with the same stack level stack from back to front (meaning `::after` stacks in front of `::before`).

However if you have any content in your element, you will need to position the content and give it `z-index: 1` to ensure that it will paint on top of both of your pseudo-element boxes, since `::after` comes after the main content and will therefore also stack in front of the content. See the `#element > p` rule in the following example.

```css
#element { 
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #222;
}

#element::before, #element::after {
    content: "";
    background-color: inherit;
    position: absolute;
}

#element::before {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    top: 40px;
    left: 88px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222); 
}

#element::after {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#element > p {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"><p>text</p></div>
```

Comment: By the way, off-topic, do you usually choose `::before` or `::after` as your default pseudo-element for your day-to-day layouting? I chose `::after` because it feels more natural to style that stuff _after_ styling the element itself. But now I'm not so sure anymore.

Comment: @Mark Boulder: Now that you mention it... I haven't been in any situation where I had to choose just one *and* neither of them made more sense than the other :S What I mentioned is just a little interesting nugget of info to keep in mind for whenever you find yourself playing with positioning and z-indexes of pseudos.

Comment: Just to add a little bit to this: the `drop-shadow()`-filter does indeed follow the alpha transparency outline of the element, which is what you're after. You can, for example, use the above technique as a baseline (sans the `filter` bit), and then add-on a `filter: drop-shadow()` scoped inside of a `@supports (filter: drop-shadow(...))`-rule, where you also remove the `box-shadow`. :-) JSBin example: http://jsbin.com/qoretoh/1/edit?html,css,output